# How to use Monaco Editor in a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I have a functional component in my React project.
I have included the Monaco editor dependency as

`import * as Monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';`

How to use `Editor` object from here to actually render and test things for monaco-editor?

I have code like below,

```
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Flex.Box auto>
        <Input.Textarea
          ref={ref}
          size="small"
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyPress={(e) => { handleKeyDown(e, value); }}
          error={error}
          readOnly={readOnly}
        />
        <MonacoEnvironment.
      </Flex.Box>
      <Flex align="flex-start" w="21px">
        {icon}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
```

I am looking at MonacoEnvironment object, but I am clueless about setting it up as an Editor.

I want to mimick the below functionality in my code,

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
  value: [
    'function x() {',
    '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
    '}'
  ].join('\n'),
  language: 'javascript'
});
```

Comment: [This video from Web Dev Simplified](https://youtu.be/iRaelG7v0OU) deals with something similar with the Quill editor. I know it is a different editor but it may help you get an idea of how to use Monaco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options for you here:

1. Add an HTML element to your render tree, which can host the editor. You have the `document.getElementById` call in the second code snippet. This requires an element with the id `container`:

```
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Flex.Box auto>
        <Input.Textarea
          ref={ref}
          size="small"
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyPress={(e) => { handleKeyDown(e, value); }}
          error={error}
          readOnly={readOnly}
        />
        <div id="container />
      </Flex.Box>
      <Flex align="flex-start" w="21px">
        {icon}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
```

2. Use a Monaco editor React wrapper (e.g. [react-monaco-editor](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor)) and add it to your render tree:

```
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Flex.Box auto>
        <Input.Textarea
          ref={ref}
          size="small"
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyPress={(e) => { handleKeyDown(e, value); }}
          error={error}
          readOnly={readOnly}
        />
        <MonacoEditor
          width="800"
          height="600"
          language="javascript"
          theme="vs-dark"
          value={code}
          options={options}
        />
      </Flex.Box>
      <Flex align="flex-start" w="21px">
        {icon}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
```

You don't need that second part then, where you manually created the editor.

Comment: I think what I want to achieve is there a way my `Input.Textarea` knows about  language="javascript"
          theme="vs-dark"
          value={code}
          options={options} attributes? I would like pass them to my `Input.Textarea`.

Comment: I don't want to have another Editor window, I want my Textarea to behave like one by inheriting the properties of MonacoEditor. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, no, that makes no sense. You want a kitchen knife to behave like a chainsaw, just by "inheriting" some of the chainsaw's properties? How can that work? If you need a chainsaw, use a chainsaw. As easy as that :-)

Comment: Is Monaco Editor able to understand the Antlr4 grammar file as language and then do auto code completion accordingly?

Comment: Please ask follow up question separately. I (and other experts) will be glad to help you out then.

Comment: Added a new question.